# Fetching logged in user in service layer with spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-integration

I have an asynchronous method in the service layer which reads the message from the queue. I need to send the received message to the subscribers of the currently logged in user.

In my controller I fetch the user as

```
(CustomUserDetail)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

which works fine but the same code in the service layer throws a 
`NullPointerException`. May be due to `SecurityContextHolder` not being called within the same request response flow rather asynchronously but at the same time I think Spring Security keeps all the user security data in the session. So it should work fine.

Can anyone suggest a workaround. How do I fetch the logged in user in the service layer?

One possible way I feel can be adding the active user to the session when the controller method pushes the message to the queue & then retrieve the user from the session in the service layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTTP session won't be available there as well.

The issue is here just because you shift the invocation from one Thread to another.

If you deal with [Spring Integration](http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/), you can consider to use [`SecurityContextPropagationChannelInterceptor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/security.html) for your `queueChannel`.

Otherwise you should *transfer* `Authentication` object to your service layer manually together with data.

Spring Security can help you with [`Executors` and `Schedulers`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#concurrency), but it doesn't have any hook to operate with queues...

Comment: thanks for the advice, I add the authentication object with the message body. Works fine now. I also tried other ways to add the user object in the session, RequestContextHolder etc. but passing the authentication object with the message is the cleanest.

Answer (score 6):

Spring `SecurityContextHolder` default mode is `MODE_THREADLOCAL` which means `SecurityContextHolder` is only available in same thread of execution.

Changing that to `MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL`, should give you access `SecurityContextHolder` in all the spawned thread.

> SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL)

should solve your problem.

Comment: This works only for the child threads spawned by the main thread. Will work fine for methods annotated with @Async but doesn't work for the queue, still gives a NPE. I cannot share security context among sibling threads (e.g. in a thread pool). Thanks for the answer though;

Comment: Is there a way to add the securitycontextobject to the thread pool or something so that every thread has access to it?

Comment: If you are using spring security 3.2 or above , you can use concurrncy support . http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#concurrency.